# [Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "0". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an issue with a project in Vue2.
I have this two errors and I can not find out the reason.
[enter image description here][1]

```
  [Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "0". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification.
found in
---> <App> at src/App.vue
```

and another error in the same file

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid value for option "components": expected an Object, but got Array.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
```

This is what I have at my app.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="#fdf8f0"
      dark
    >
    <div id="Logo" class="container"></div>
    <v-btn v-if="!!token" @click="$store.commit('resetToken')">
      <span>Desconectar</span>
      <v-icon>mdiLogout</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <Login v-if="token === ''" />
      <!-- <Business v-if="token !== ''" /> -->
      <Business class="d-none" />
      <Offers v-if="token !== ''" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Business from './components/Business.vue';
import Offers from './components/Offers.vue';

export default {
  name:'app',
  components: {
    Login,
    Business,
    Offers
  },
  computed: {
    token () {
      return this.$store.state.token
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The error means that there's really components array in some component. There's no "appwoowbe" or whatever it is in the code you posted